# C++ / compilation of a program fatal error: QtGui/qwidget.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, qmake

I've downloaded a linux application which required qt4. 
I have it already on my computer.

I have this following error when I want to compile the program using **make** in the terminal.

```
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/util_convert.dir/moc_planeviewer.cxx.o
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtGui/QMainWindow:1:0,
             from /home/Desktop/plane/src/planeviewer.h:3,
             from /home/Desktop/plane/src/moc_planeviewer.cxx:9:
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qmainwindow.h:45:27: fatal error: QtGui/qwidget.h: No such file or directory
 #include <QtGui/qwidget.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/util_convert.dir/moc_planviewer.cxx.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/util_convert.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I don't understand because I checked already everything.
I have the following input for those different commands line:

**qmake --version**

```
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

**locate qwidget.h**

```
/opt/qt/5.4/android_armv7/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h
/opt/qt/5.4/gcc_64/include/QtWidgets/qwidget.h
/usr/include/qt4/Qt/qwidget.h
/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/qwidget.h
```

So the file already exists.

**The CmakeList in case**

```
find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization program_options python)
find_package(PythonLibs 2.6 REQUIRED)

set(QT_USE_QTSVG TRUE)
set(QT_USE_QTXML TRUE)
set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
find_package(OpenGL)
find_package( Qt4 REQUIRED )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTSVG_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${QT_QTXML_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_QTOPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

QT4_WRAP_UI(util_convert_FORMS planeviewer.ui)
QT4_WRAP_CPP(util_convert_MOCS planeviewer.h planewidget.h)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(util_convert ${util_convert_FORMS} ${util_convert_MOCS} plane.cpp util_convert.cpp planeviewer.cpp planewidget.cpp objects.cpp coordinates.cpp utils.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(util_convert ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTSVG_LIBRARY}
                                  ${QT_QTXML_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
```

**How I compile**:

Go to src/ then do **cmake .** and finally **make**.
The error happened at the make step.

Before posting this, I already searched on the internet but didn't find a solution yet.

Can someone helps me ?

Comment: Please add the exact invocation of the compiler, maybe some arguments are wrong.

Comment: I've edited my post. I just did cmake and then make in the terminal.

Comment: Yes, but in the first snippet, can you ADD the compiler command line that triggered that error?

Comment: Please print values of cmake variables related to Qt, such as `QT_QTCORE_INCLUDE_DIR`. Maybe they have wrong values.

Comment: I think you need add path `/usr/include/qt4/` to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`

Comment: It worked @gomons ! 
I don't know why the author of the code didn't put this line. 
Anyway, Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`. I think that in your example `QT_QTGUI_INCLUDE_DIR` variable has value `/usr/include/qt4/QtGui`, but you need add `/usr/include/qt4` to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`, because in code include statement useses path `<QtGui/qwidget.h>`:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/qt4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @gomons, I was able to compile it.

I added in the CmakeList the following line:

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("/usr/include/qt4/")
```